# SQL Query on tables using Joins and return distinct records

Tags: sql

I am performing SQL Query to filter some result, Query is built and yielding result but all the repeated records are also coming. So can any one help me out with this. I need Distinct records and querying on 3 different tables.

My Query :

```
 SELECT TOP 10 leafname                                        AS 'File Name', 
              MIN(Docs.dirname)                               AS 'Web Directory' 
              , 
              extension                                       AS 
              'File Type', 
              a.tp_title                                      AS 'Created By', 
              a.tp_login                                      AS 'Login Name', 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), userdata.tp_created, 106)  AS 'Created Date', 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), userdata.tp_modified, 106) AS 'Modified Date' 
              , 
              ( CAST(( CAST(CAST(size AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) / 1024 
                            AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) / 1024 ) AS 
                       NUMERIC(18, 2)) )                      AS 'Size in MB' 
--,b.tp_Title as Editor,b.tp_Login as EditorLogin 
FROM   Docs WITH(nolock) 
       INNER JOIN UserData WITH(nolock) 
               ON Docs.siteid = userdata.tp_siteid 
       INNER JOIN Webs WITH(nolock) 
               ON Docs.webid = Webs.id 
       INNER JOIN Sites WITH(nolock) 
               ON Webs.siteid = SItes.id 
       INNER JOIN UserInfo AS a WITH(nolock) 
               ON a.tp_id = UserData.tp_author 
                  AND a.tp_siteid = SItes.id 
WHERE  ( leafname LIKE 'Default.aspx' 
          OR extension LIKE 'aspx' ) 
       AND dirname NOT LIKE '%personal%' 
       AND dirname NOT LIKE '%_catalogs%' 
       AND Docs.dirname != '' 
--order by dirname 
GROUP  BY leafname, 
          Docs.dirname, 
          extension, 
          a.tp_title, 
          a.tp_login, 
          userdata.tp_created, 
          userdata.tp_modified, 
          Docs.size
```

Any Help..???

Comment: ( CAST(( CAST(CAST(size AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) / 1024 AS 
NUMERIC(18, 2)) / 1024 ) AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) ) AS 'Size in MB'  seems somewhat complex of false. Please check it.

Comment: ok, got it. You have used cast as numeric.

Answer (score 0):

May be it would work for you. Try this approach.

```
select distinct tmp.* from (
SELECT TOP 10 
leafname AS 'File Name', 
MIN(Docs.dirname) AS 'Web Directory',
extension AS 'File Type', 
a.tp_title AS 'Created By', 
a.tp_login AS 'Login Name', 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), userdata.tp_created, 106)  AS 'Created Date', 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), userdata.tp_modified, 106) AS 'Modified Date', 
( CAST(( CAST(CAST(size AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) / 1024 AS 
NUMERIC(18, 2)) / 1024 ) AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) ) AS 'Size in MB' 
--,b.tp_Title as Editor,b.tp_Login as EditorLogin 
FROM   Docs WITH(nolock) 
       INNER JOIN UserData WITH(nolock) 
               ON Docs.siteid = userdata.tp_siteid 
       INNER JOIN Webs WITH(nolock) 
               ON Docs.webid = Webs.id 
       INNER JOIN Sites WITH(nolock) 
               ON Webs.siteid = SItes.id 
       INNER JOIN UserInfo AS a WITH(nolock) 
               ON a.tp_id = UserData.tp_author 
                  AND a.tp_siteid = SItes.id 
WHERE  ( leafname LIKE 'Default.aspx' 
          OR extension LIKE 'aspx' ) 
       AND dirname NOT LIKE '%personal%' 
       AND dirname NOT LIKE '%_catalogs%' 
       AND Docs.dirname != '' 
--order by dirname 
GROUP  BY leafname, 
          Docs.dirname, 
          extension, 
          a.tp_title, 
          a.tp_login, 
          userdata.tp_created, 
          userdata.tp_modified, 
          Docs.size 
) as tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please write a subset of the result set with the duplicated data.
What's the purpose of using the MIN() function !?
Try using DISTINCT where needed.

best practice: 
1) Try to use a table alias before each column name (like a.tp_id) to avoid ambiguos fields.
2) use AS [alias] instead of AS 'alias'